# How close can we programmatically get to the hardware of an Android device?

Tags: android, sdk, hardware

the camera of my mobile (running Eclair-update1) keeps being non-responsive in 90% of the time, so I assumed a hardware defect at first. After whiping the cache and the phone user data sereval times it worked again. At least for a while. Now it stopped working again.

Browsing the net I found quite some users who experience the same problem and had a hard time after whiping their user data off the device.

So my question would be: how close can I get to the hardware with the SDK? I'd like to write an app to influence hardware states (e.g. re-initializing the camera, remounting the SDcard aso.), but I'd prefer doing it - if possible - with the SDK instead of NDK.

Thanks in advance!
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a question of sdk vs. ndk, but of underlying operating system level permissions preventing ordinary (aftermarket vs. manufacturer/carrier installed) android applications in general from doing raw hardware access.

Comment: So that means there is simply no way to pass by dig through the Java VM? I'd suppose a rooted device should give more chances.

Comment: Piercing the java vm is no problem at all (other than that the native libs you would be talking to underneath aren't stable and may change between android versions), but without being the superuser this gets you relatively little capability you didn't have from java - it's the linux user security mechanism that limits you, not the "java" (actually dalvik) vm.  As root you can directly access device files, (probably) change the kernel, load new drivers, whatever.

Answer (score -1):

- Download Android SDK to your computer
- Boot device to recovery
- Connect USB cable to PC
- Run `adb shell` then
- `umount /data`
- `umount /system`
- `e2fsck -fv /dev/block/stl9`
- `e2fsck -fv /dev/block/stl10`

Taken from [forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1396366](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1396366)