# Low level operations with SD card on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

is it possible to have low level access in Android with Java/NDK to create for example card scanner like scandisk or card defragmenter? I move a lots of stuff around my card and it gets fragmented quickly. I have experience with FAT32 defragmenting on Windows, but I'dliek to do this on Android.

Comment: This isn't really programming related.

Answer (score 2):

Fragmentation does not affect SD card as much as it affect a harddrive since SD card does not have spinning parts or moving heads, the difference between random access vs sequential access of an SD card is negligible.

In other words, SD card does not need defragmenting; in fact defragmenting an SD card will only lower the life span of your SD card since the memory cells of an SD card have a limit on the number of read/write that you can do on them.

And if you need to "scandisk" (or "fsck" in Unix/Linux-speak, stands for "File System ChecK"), I don't think the Android's default shell comes with fsck, but you should be able to fsck the SD card from your computer.

Comment: try fragmenting an SD card so that one new MP3 file is shattered into 1000 pieces. Then try reading from that file. Then try reading from a contiguous file.

Comment: @Axarydax: and yet, there will be negligible difference; fragmentation do cause some small overhead for parsing and processing metadata and finding empty blocks. However, if you do ever get your file fragmented into 1000 pieces, you have another problem, namely you're using FAT. In practice, if you're using a decent filesystem, it is extremely hard to create more than a few fragments (an average MP3 file is 4MB and it got to be a really dumb filesystem to ever felt the need to search 1000 free spaces, each 4kb in size, while it has a 4MB block over there).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to one of [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133874/how-close-can-we-programmatically-get-to-the-hardware-of-an-android-device).

Comment: Sort of, in that the issue is operating system level permissions rather than sdk vs ndk.  But Lie Ryan's suggesting of doing the fsck or whatever from an external machine leverages a permissions bypass mechanism unique to the sdcard.